# Probability of getting a boy (explanation of answer given in textbook)

Tags: probability

Context:In the countryside, where sons traditionally have been valued, if the first child is a son, the couple may have no more children. But if the first child is a daughter, the couple may have another child. Regardless of the sex of the second child, no more are permitted. How will this policy affect the mix of males and females?

Question:To pose the question mathematically, what is the probability that a randomly selected child from the countryside is a boy?

Answer:Let B be the event that the randomly selected child from the countryside is a boy. Let E be the event that the randomly selected child is the first child of the family and F be the event that he or she is the second child of the family. Clearly, P(E) = 2/3 and P(F) = 1/3. By the law of total probability,

$$P(B)=P(B|E)P(E)*P(B|F)P(F)=1/2*2/3+1/2*1/3=1/2$$

I do not get why the probabilty of picking the first child is 2/3. The sample space is $$\{B,G,GG,GB\} $$ There are 4 first children out of 6, is that why it is 2/3? But the probability of picking a boy in a one child family is 1/2. Therefore I thought that the the probability of E should be$$ P(E)=1/2+1/2 * P(\text{picking first child among } \{G,GG,GB\})$$. Thus in my opinion, there are not enough assumptions specified in the question. Of course the probability of getting a boy or girl at any time is 1/2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is making an implicit assumption that all families with a first child of a daughter have a second child. Thus, the effective sample space is $\{B,GG,GB\}$. The probability of $B$ is $0.5$, with $GG$ and $GB$ having equal probability each summing to $0.5$, i.e., they are each $0.25$. Thus, among $n$ families, there will be $0.5n$ first boys and $0.5n$ first girls, but $0.5 \times 0.5n = 0.25n$ second girls and $0.25n$ second boys. Thus, there are $0.5n + 0.5n = n$ first children out of a total of $0.5n + 0.5n + 0.25n + 0.25n = 1.5n$ children, so the probability of a first child is $\frac{n}{1.5n} = \frac{2}{3}$. Note if you divide the numbers by  $n$, or equivalently set $n = 1$, you'll get the average values per family, with this being $0.5$ each of first boys and girls, and $0.25$ each of second boys and girls.

Also, in addition to the explanation given in the book, note there are $0.5n$ first children which are boys and $0.25n$ second children which are boys. Thus, as you stated, the probability of a boy would be $\frac{0.75n}{1.5n} = 0.5$.

Comment: Given your assumption. Suppose we think of it this way. Encode a boy as $B_1$ if he is a boy from a one-child family. A girl with $G_1$ if she is the first girl from a 2 child family, etc. Then the sample space is $\{B_1,G_1G_2,G_1B_2\}$. Arrange all your children in a row and select one of them randomly. Then the probability of $E$ is the probability of picking $B_1$ or $G_1$. Which is $1/2+1/2*1/2=3/4$

Comment: @johnson Please be careful of $G_1$ repeated in $2$ places, so you can't count that child twice. Also, note the probability of each element in the sample space, among *all* children, is equal, i.e, each one is $1/3$. This is what I tried to show in my answer using $n$ children for $B_1$ and $G_1$, but just $0.5n$ for $G_2$ and $B_2$. The probability of the $B_1$ is thus $\frac{1}{3}$, with the same probability for $G_1$, so the total is $2/3$. Here's another way. Each family of $1$st girl has a $2$nd child, so # $1$st girls = # $2$nd children, & # $1$st boys = # $1$st girls, so each is $1/3$.

Comment: @johnson The issue is these are probabilities of individual events, but the question is asking for population type probabilities, so you need to consider, one way or another, how many events each of those possibilities represent among the total population. The probability of a $1$st boy or girl is each $1/2$, but the second children only occur where the first child is a girl. As such, for every $1$st child which is a boy, there's equally likely to be $2$ other children of a first girl and then a second girl or boy. Thus, only $1/3$ of children are first boys, thus $1/3$ are first girls, ...

Comment: @johnson (cont.) $1/6$ are $2$nd boys and $1/6$ are $2$nd girls. Thus, $1/3 + 1/3 = 2/3$ are first children, $1/6 + 1/6 = 1/3$ are second children, and $1/3 + 1/6 = 1/2$ are boys which are first or second children. Another way to consider this is in terms of families. $1/2$ of families have a first boy. Among the $1/2$ of families with a first girl, $1/2$ of them have a second girl & $1/2$ have a second boy, for $1/4$ each. However, the families have *different* sizes, so they affect the total # of children differently, as I've explained here.

Comment: @johnson One way to use $(1/2,1/4,1/4)$ is to consider the average # of children per parent being $1/2$ for a first boy, $1/2$ for a first girl, $1/2 \times 1/2 = 1/4$ for a $2$nd girl and $1/2 \times 1/2 = 1/4$ for a $2$nd boy, for a total of $1/2 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 = 3/2$. Thus, the probability of a first boy is $\frac{1/2}{3/2} = 1/3$, a first girl is also $\frac{1/2}{3/2} = 1/3$ and each of the $2$nd children is $\frac{1/4}{3/2} = 1/6$. Perhaps this helps you to understand. Note this is still implicitly using $n$, but it shows how $(1/2,1/4,1/4)$ fits into the handling as well.

Answer (score 2):

Although the sample space is that $B, G, GB, GG$ a family with only one girl will never happen.  Once a girl is born the family will have a second child in a try for a boy.  (Bleagh)

So half the families will have one boy.  One quarter of the families will have a boy and a girl, and one quarter of the families will have $2$ girls.

But then the book does a complicated conditional probability.  Why? How cares if the child you pick is  first born or second.  Just count how many boys and girls there are.

If there are $n$ families there will by $\frac n2$ boys from the $\frac n2$ $1$ boy families, and $\frac n4$ boys from the $\frac n4$ boy and girl families.  That's $\frac {3n}4$ boys.  There are $\frac n4$ girls from that boy and girl families, and $2*\frac n4$ girls from the $2$ girl families.

So there are $\frac {3n}4$ boys and $\frac {3n}4$ girls and as those are equal the probability is $\frac 12$.

FWIW (which isnt much) There are $n$ first borns and $\frac n2$ second borns but I don't see why that is important.  Oh.... I guess have the first borns are boys and half the second born are boys so... again probability is $\frac 12$.